# using "case" in statement of "where in"-

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to apply multi-language support on my site. I've created a table like that:

```
id | textID | langID |   text   | status
1  | 1453   | 36     | sign up  |  1
2  | 1453   | 147    | kayıt ol |  1
3  | 1454   | 36     | login    |  1
```

I've created an sql like that:

SQL ;

```
SELECT `textID`
     , `text` 
  FROM `text` 
 WHERE `langID` = ( CASE WHEN `langID` = '147' and `status` THEN '147' ELSE '36' END ) 
   and `textID` in ('1453','1454')
```

RESULT ;

```
textID  | text
1453    | sign up
1453    | kayıt ol
1454    | login
```

1453,1454 is inside the "where in" but my code show two language for 1453,how should I execute sql for one language or default language ?

Comment: Please post your table structure and sql scripts in the body of your post, and not in links.

Comment: Explain exactly what you are trying to achieve - your case statement seems self defeating when status is false for langID = 147 - it will return 36 & so be comparing langID in the query to that value which we know is 147.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `textID`, `text` 
FROM `text` 
WHERE `textID` IN (1453, 1454) AND `langID` = 147

UNION

SELECT `textID`, `text`
FROM `text` 
WHERE `textID` NOT IN (
    SELECT `textID` 
    FROM `text` 
    WHERE `textID` IN (1453, 1454) AND `langID` = 147
) AND `langID` = 36
```